# Modelling hierarchical data in RavenDb

Tags: database, nosql, ravendb, recursive-query

In RavenDb, I have to store hierarchical data and I need to query it recursively. The performance is the biggest concern here.

What I have is similar to the following one:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Category Parent { get; set; }
}
```

In this case, if I store the parent category inside the document itself, it will hard for me to manage the data as I will duplicating the categories all over the place.

So, to make that easy, I can store this as below:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

But in that case I'm not sure how the performance will be here as I will have millions of records and I need to create the category tree from this reference.

Is there a certain decision in RavenDb on how to model this type of data when the performance is the biggest concern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hierarchies are usually best modeled in one document that defines the hierarchy. In your situation that would be to define the categories tree, where the categories themselves can be represented by standalone documents (and thus hold Name, Description etc, and allow for other collection to reference them), or not.

Modeled from code a Category document would look something like this:

```
public class Category
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // other meta-data that you want to store per category, like image etc
}
```

And the hierarchy tree document can be serialized from a class like the following, where this class can have methods for making nodes in it easily accessible:

```
public class CategoriesHierarchyTree
{
    public class Node
    {
       public string CategoryId { get; set; }
       public List<Node> Children { get; set; }
    }

    public List<Node> RootCategories { get; private set; }

    // various methods for looking up and updating tree structure
}
```

This approach of hierarchy-tree has several important advantages:

1. One transactional scope - when the tree changes, the tree changes in one transaction, always. You cannot get affected by multiple concurrent changes to the tree since you can leverage optimistic concurrency when editing this one document. Using the approach you propose it is impossible to guarantee that therefore harder to guarantee the completeness and correctness of the hierarchy tree over time. If you think of a hierarchy as a tree, it actually makes a lot of sense to have each change lock the entire tree until it completes. The hierarchy tree is one entity.
2. Caching - the entire hierarchy can be quickly and efficiently cached, even using aggressive caching which will minimize the times the server is accessed with queries on hierarchy.
3. All operations are done entirely in-memory - since its one document, aka object, all queries on the hierarchy (whose the parent of, list of children etc) are made entirely in-memory and effectively cost close to nothing to perform. Using an index with Recurse() to answer such queries is order of magnitude costlier (network costs and computational). You mention performance is the biggest concern - so this is a winner.
4. Multiple parents per category, no denormalization - if a category document is saved outside the hierarchy tree, like demonstrated above, you can effectively put a category under multiple parents without the need to denormalize. All category data is in one place, in a document outside of the tree, and the tree only holds a reference to the category.

I will highly recommend going with this approach. It is a bit of a shift from the relational mindset, but its so worth it, even when the tree grows big.

Comment: thanks! This really helps. In this case, I will duplicate a category in multiple places (maybe 1000 times, who knows). So, in RavenDb, is there any way to update a category info in multiple places in ones? or should I find them one by one and update them individually? I looked at batch update here (http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/set-based-operations) but not sure if this is the one that I need.

Comment: I'm not following - why would you need to update many occurrences of the category at once? in what I suggested, you only have one occurrence of the category as a document, and the hierarchy tree just uses the category ID to define who are its parents - potentially having more than one.

Comment: The one thing I see as an issue with this, and admittedly this may just be my 'newness' to this style, is given a particular category's ID, how can I get all of its children?  This doesn't let you query the hierarchy to get those children's IDs unless you know the path all the way back to the root and this also doesn't easily let you get those parents. Isn't this just swapping one traversal direction's priority for the other--down vs up?

Comment: Also, by your own multi-parent definition as a benefit, it means my above *can't* be figured out since there theoretically could be multiple paths back to the root.

Comment: One way to do it is to recursively iterate through all the nodes and flatten it into a dictionary.